# Databricks can't "rescue" data from Parquet using schemaEvolutionMode="rescue", raises an error instead

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, parquet, databricks-autoloader

I have parquet files with evolving schema, I need to load all of them into single Delta Table. My goal is to use Autoloader and `schemaEvolutionMode`="`rescue`" (so all fields from the source which are not aligned with the target schema should fall into "`_rescued_data`" column). I also provide `.schema(target_schema)` for autoloader.
But when I read from some files I get this error:

```
Invalid Spark read type: expected optional group my_column (LIST) 
{ repeated group list { optional binary element (STRING); } } 
to be list but found Some(StringType)
```

`my_column` has data type String in the target table.

So why it was not loaded into `_rescued_data` column and raised the error instead?

The code which I'm using:

```
read_options = {
"cloudFiles.format": "parquet",
"cloudFiles.schemaLocation: "some location",
"cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode": "rescue"
}
 
spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
.options(**read_options)
.schema(target_schema)
.load("source_path")
.foreachBatch(<save function>)
.outputMode("append")
.trigger("availableNow", True)
.start()
```

Databricks version is 13.2 (Spark 3.4.0, Scala 2.12)

Comment: How did you define the `target_schema` ?

Comment: as sql list of columns and their data types - "some_column int, my_column string, etc.."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the error was that "rescued_data" column was cleared after reading the dataframe (before writing).

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting indicates that a column in your Parquet file doesn't match the expected schema, and it is not falling into the "**_rescued_data**"  column as expected.

For example I have used a CSV file with schema evolution when using Delta Lake with Autoloader in  Spark Streaming job.

The below code performs Autoloader with schema inference and schema evolution mode "`rescue`"

In a scenario where you do not want stop the stream.
New columns have to be rescued columns and later apply transformation

```
df = (spark.readStream
.format("cloudFiles")
.option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")
.option("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes", "true")
.option("cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode", "rescue") 
.option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", schema_loc)
.load(source_location)
)
query = (df.writeStream
.format("delta")
.option("checkpointLocation", checkpoints_loc)
.outputMode("overwrite")
.option("mergeSchema", "true")
.start(target_location)
)
```

**To Enable schema inference**

```
.option("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes", "true")
```

**Schema evolution mode**

```
.option("cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode", "rescue")
```

**schema evolution**

```
.option("mergeSchema", "true")
```

[image]

In a scenario where you do not want stop the stream.
New cols have to rescued col and later apply transformation

```
SparkSession.builder.appName("DeltaWithAutomaticRetries").config("spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled", "true").getOrCreate()
```

The above code will enable automatic retries for schema evolution in Delta Lake

Know more [How does Auto Loader schema evolution work?](https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/auto-loader/schema.html#how-does-auto-loader-schema-evolution-work)